# GoYAML struct slices

Tags: go, yaml, slice

I am attempting to learn goyaml, and am having some issues with attempting to produce slices from yaml. I can marshal my struct into this example yaml, but I cannot unmarshal the same yaml back into the struct.

```
 input:
  file:
  - file: stdin
  webservice:
  - port: "0000"
    address: 0.0.0.0
processing:
  regex:
  - regex: ^(this)*
    mapping: (1) thing
output:
  file:
  - file: stdout
  webservice:
  - port: "0000"
    address: 0.0.0.0
```

struct:

```
type Configuration struct{
    Input ioInstance
    Processing ProcessingInstance
    Output ioInstance
}

type ioInstance struct {
    File []FileInstance
    Webservice []WebserviceInstance
}

type FileInstance struct {
    File string
}

type WebserviceInstance struct  {
    Port string
    Address string
}

type ProcessingInstance struct {
    Regex []RegexInstance
}

type RegexInstance struct {
    Regex string
    Mapping string
}
```

When testing unmarshaling I'm getting reflect errors, as I understand it I think I may need to re-approach the design without struct slices, I was hoping someone could offer some insight into this?

errors:

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value [recovered]
    panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value [recovered]
    panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value
```

Comment: are you using the newest package? "github.com/go-yaml/yaml" has been moved to "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works just fine for me, outputting the original yaml text as it should:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

func main() {
    c := &Configuration{}
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlText), c) 
    buf, _ := yaml.Marshal(c)
    fmt.Println(string(buf))
}

var yamlText = ` 
input:
  file:
  - file: stdin
  webservice:
  - port: "0000"
    address: 0.0.0.0
processing:
  regex:
  - regex: ^(this)*
    mapping: (1) thing
output:
  file:
  - file: stdout
  webservice:
  - port: "0000"
    address: 0.0.0.0
`

type Configuration struct {
    Input      ioInstance
    Processing ProcessingInstance
    Output     ioInstance
}

type ioInstance struct {
    File       []FileInstance
    Webservice []WebserviceInstance
}

type FileInstance struct {
    File string
}

type WebserviceInstance struct {
    Port    string
    Address string
}

type ProcessingInstance struct {
    Regex []RegexInstance
}

type RegexInstance struct {
    Regex   string
    Mapping string
}
```

Output:

```
input:
  file:
  - file: stdin
  webservice:
  - port: "0000"
    address: 0.0.0.0
processing:
  regex:
  - regex: ^(this)*
    mapping: (1) thing
output:
  file:
  - file: stdout
  webservice:
  - port: "0000"
    address: 0.0.0.0
```

(Of course you should *not* ignore errors in your actual code, like I'm doing here.)

EDIT:

`Unmarshal` needs a *pointer* to a struct in order to set its fields. If you call it with a plain struct value, it receives only a *copy* of the original struct (because in Go *everything* is passed as a copy), and therefore couldn't possibly alter the fields of the original struct.

Therefore, you have basically two options:

You can define and initialize `c` with `c := &Configuration{}`, i.e. defining it as a pointer to type `Configuration` while simultaneously pointing it to a new, zeroed `Configuration` value. Then you can call `yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlText), c)`.

Alternatively you can define `c` with `var c Configuration`, which means `c` is not a pointer, but a new zero value of type `Configuration`. In this case you need to explicitly pass a pointer to that value when you call `Unmarshal`: `yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlText), &c)`.

Note that the pointer you pass to Unmarshal must point to an *existing* `Configuration` value. `var c *Configuration` would define `c` as a pointer, but passing it immediately to `Unmarshal` would lead to an panic, as it's value is `nil`; it doesn't point to an existing `Configuration` value.

Also, in my code above there was originally a little typo, which is now fixed (though the code still worked). I wrote both `c := &Configuration{}` and `yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlText), &c)`, so I actually passed `Unmarshal` *a pointer to a pointer to a struct*, which `Unmarshal` was able to handle without issues.

Comment: This worked! Thanks
I was previously using
`var config Configuration`

to initialize

Can you explain why that works and this doesn't?

Comment: @TimTanasse, I added the explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Looks like I'm a bit too used to Java